# Admob ad mediation with Facebook Audience Network on React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, admob, facebook-audience-network

I have a React Native app in which I am already serving admob ads. Now I want to integrate ad mediation with Facebook Audience network and I configured everything according to [this guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/facebook) until step 3

In step 4 it says to import FAN SDK and adapter, which sdk should I use for React Native app? What else do I need to configure?